# While running Cron through Command prompt getting "exec function is disabled. " error in magento2

Tags: magento2, error, cron

while trying to run Cron through Command Prompt getting below error -

Command  -  `php bin/magento cron:run`

Getting Error -

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
>                    exec function is disabled.

Can you plz let me know how to enable 'exec' function and run default group name cron properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from `/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Shell.php` :

```
    $disabled = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
    if (in_array('exec', $disabled)) {
        throw new Exception("exec function is disabled.");
    }
    exec($command, $output, $exitCode);
```

**Basically to be able to execute the command, Magento needs to run the PHP `exec` function.**

Some hosting providers disable this function for security reason and in your case that's what the problem is.

I suggest you contact your hosting provider in order to re enable the `exec` method for your site.

Comment: you are genius bro...let me check with hosting provider.

Comment: Here is the host provider reply - when running php via apache it differs from when running via cron . 
So in my case this command works - Go to your magento 2 root then run -> `php -c ~/php.ini bin/magento cron:run`

Comment: @Atul sweet glad you fixed your issue

Comment: thx you gave me the direction.. :)

Comment: My hosting provider does not want to take the risk and refuses to enable php exec function. Is there any other way I can perform my cron:run?

Comment: @ElsdenIep do you get the other solution.

Answer (score 5):

Use a custom php.ini for the cron jobs:

`/usr/local/bin/php -c customphp.ini bin/magento cron:run`

Just take a copy of the original php.ini. Search for disable_functions and remove exec from the list.

There is no need to open exec for the web application.

Comment: Or define the config value directly (no need to duplicate your php.ini): `php -d disable_functions= bin/magento cron:run`

Comment: That's indeed easier. Thanks for the tip!