# There has been an error processing you request

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

I tried activating production mode, However i got an error saying exec is disabled. So i activated the production mode by using **php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s**. Then when i tried to access the site, i got exception printing error. So i reversed to default mode and everything works fine.
Could you please tell me what might be the error ? i need to set my site to production mode ASAP.

Comment: Check the report log under var/report for production mode. Something maybe generated or static content directory permission issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your hosting provider has disabled php exec(). You need to ask your hosting provider to enable it.

Basically the error is coming from Shell.php file residing in /lib/internal/Magento/Framework. See the code below

```
$disabled = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
if (in_array('exec', $disabled)) {
    throw new Exception("exec function is disabled.");
}
exec($command, $output, $exitCode);
```

Ref: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134257/77673

Hope it helped you

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your help, But i have read that most hosting providers don't enable php exec as it has security risks. Is there any other way i can enable production mode without breaking my site ?

Comment: I understand but I am worried if there is any other way. There is one manual and cumbersome process I found but not suitable for constant updates. Link : https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/exec-function-is-disabled-Production-Mode-problem/m-p/88570/highlight/true#M4283

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have read, ill talk to my hosting providers first and let you know. Btw is switching to production mode a must  ?

Comment: Switching to production mode will give you faster access speed since it generates the caches. It will increase the speed of your site by immense difference. So its preferred to keep all live sites in production mode.

Comment: Dear, My hosting providers sorted it out. Thank you very much for the support.

Comment: Great, so that was the only solution at this moment. Did they enabled exec() ?

Comment: Yes Adbul, They did have an option in php config where i could remove the disabled functions myself.

Comment: Great, If the solution was relevant kindly accept & upvote the answer. If it wasn't then kindly add you solution so that others will be beneficial.

Comment: ill up vote right away :)